# Coloring separate rows based on matching of data in key cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, format

i have a excel file as

[image]

i want change the sheet that after sort on key column(MasterID), any rows same as key column change color to similar.
for example

[image]

Comment: why close this post?

Comment: When you say "after sorting on MasterID" any rows "the same as MasterID" change color, what do you mean? Do you mean any matching values in "MasterID" are colored the same (as the picture indicates) or do you mean that whatever you sort to show on "MasterID" is colored and others are hidden (which is what a filter does)?

Comment: Firstly, I sort the sheet. I don't filter it.My meaning is the picture indicates.

Comment: Are you looking to use conditional formatting or a macro? What have you tried already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm using conditional formatting, but this is done manually. (New Rule: =$a1=12, format...
New Rule: =$a1=15, format…,  
…)
MasterID must write a separate rule for each.
I'd be so rules are automatically generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add a column in end of sheet (column E).
2. in cell E2, set formula : =MOD(IF(ROW()=2,1,IF(A2=A1,E1,E1+1)),2)
3. add new rule, {=$E1="" format ...} and {=$E1=1 format ...} and {=$E1=2 format}